# Print tab character in fish

Tags: fish

In bash I could either do `echo -e "a\tb"` or `echo a$'\t'b`.

How do you do this in fish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`\t`, without quotes.](http://fishshell.com/user_doc/index.html#escapes) Same thing for other control characters (`\n` for a newline, etc.).